# CUPS - Printer stuck at "waiting for job to complete"

Tags: fedora, printing, cups, printer

I'm on Fedora 24 and am trying to print.

My printer is a Brother MFC-J6520DW which worked well on Debian. I installed the driver from Brother's webpage.

Whenever I try to print a test page, the printer status never gets beyond "Processing - Waiting for job to complete". On the screen of the printer itself it says "Retrieving Data". After a very long time (some minutes) the printer releases an empty page.

The printer sits on a network and works fine from other non-Fedora devices.

I have tried the following:

- explicitly allow MyUser in the CUPS webinterface (locahost:631)
- ensured that the `ipp` and `ipp-client` services are trusted by the firewall (I understand that these are needed for printing).

Not really sure what to do next to try to fix this....

Comment: Look at `/var/log/cups/*`

Comment: @waltinator, there is `access_log` in there as well as `page_log`, however both files seem to be empty

Answer (score 1):

I've just had the same problem, albeit with a Canon MF229dw on Linux Mint, butg the solution was simply to change the connection type to "AppSocket/HP JetDirect".

Comment: Thanks Colin. I upgraded to Fedora 25 and the problem disappeared.... I'll check what connection type F25 offers and if this is the same